how to make a return type of `TResponse | TError`?
I'm trying to find a way to have a return type of TData | TError.
This is what I tried (TS Playground):
type MyResponse = {
  data: any;
}

type UIError<TError = unknown> = {
  error: TError;
}

abstract class BaseClass {
  public abstract userAuth<
    TResponse extends MyResponse = MyResponse,
    TError extends UIError = UIError
  >(): Promise<TResponse | TError>;
}

class TestClass extends BaseClass {
  public userAuth<
    TResponse extends MyResponse = MyResponse,
    TError extends UIError = UIError<any>>(): Promise<TResponse | TError> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
}

but in TestClass I keep getting:
Type 'MyResponse | UIError<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'TResponse | TError'

Any ideas on how to fix it?
Thanks

The problem is that in your subclass, TError in userAuth extends UIError<unknown>. The return type of a subclass function must be assignable to the return type of the parent class function definition being implemented, in this case TError extends UIError. However, TError extends UIError can be something more specific than UIError<unknown>, for example, UIError<string> would also satisfy TError. That's why UIError<unknown> in TestClass would not be assignable to TError in BaseClass.
You could try to extend the generic parameter in UIError, instead of trying to extend UIError directly. But extends unknown is actually pointless.
There is another error that you would find out if you return an UIError in `TestClass:
'TError' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'
, which can be fixed if you just remove the second generic parameter in userAuth. This reduces your example to something like this:
abstract class BaseClass {
  public abstract userAuth<
    TResponse extends MyResponse = MyResponse,
  >(): Promise<TResponse | UIError>;
}

class TestClass extends BaseClass {
  public userAuth<
    TResponse extends MyResponse = MyResponse,
  >(): Promise<TResponse | UIError<any>> {
    return Promise.resolve({
      error: "",
    });
  }
}

If you are happy to make your classes generic, you can also do something like this:
abstract class BaseClass<
  TResponse extends MyResponse = MyResponse,
  TError extends UIError = UIError,
> {
  public abstract userAuth(): Promise<TResponse | TError>;
}

class TestClass extends BaseClass<MyResponse, UIError<any>> {
  public async userAuth() {
    return { error: "" };
  }
}

